# Como desabilitar o Forms Authenitcation para a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web.config, forms-authentication

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC e dentro dele tem a Web Api, quando uma requisição envia um token inválido, o forms authentication redireciona para a página de login, mas eu preciso que ele apenas retorne um erro Http 401, pois é uma Api Rest. Já tentei usar a tag  no Web.config, mas não surtiu efeito.

```
  <location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: já tentou return Unauthorized(); ?

Comment: @Fábio Lima, poderia adicionar a resolução do problema como uma resposta, assim saberemos melhor que encontrou uma solução. rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Estranho você ter configuração de FormsAuthentication num projeto Web API. De qualquer forma, para desabilitar o FormsAuthentication, use:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="None" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLUÇÃO]
Para fazer o que eu estava pretendendo, encontrei uma implementação onde se fazia uma implementação de uma interface `IHttpModule`.

```
public class SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule : IHttpModule {

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs args) {
        var context = (HttpApplication)source;
        var response = context.Response;
        var request = context.Request;

        if (response.StatusCode == 302 && request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("~"+ConstantesApi.API_URL)) {

            response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            response.ClearContent(); // limpra o conteúdo
            response.StatusCode = 401; // Coloca o código de erro http
            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true; // pula o redirecionamento do forms authentication
            response.RedirectLocation = null; // tira o redirecionamento
            response.Output.Write("{\"message\": \"Erro ao autenticar\"}"); // escreve na saída do response
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }

}
```

Depois criei um arquivo para fazer a vinculação do módulo ao sistema na execução

```
// Carrega o módulo no start da aplicação
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(FormsAuthenticationConfig), "Register" /* Método chamado na classe*/)]
namespace Unitins.Egresso.MVC.App_Start {
    public static class FormsAuthenticationConfig {
        public static void Register() {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule));
        }
    }
}
```

Fonte: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/